# prime index coefficients of $L$-functions of Elliptic Curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ and analytical rank

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I have searched without success if there was any known relationships or conjectures between the rank and the prime index coefficients of the $L$-functions of a modular elliptic curves. Anyone has a suggestion or some references ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you be more specific? The obvious one is [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture) and its generalizations.

Comment: For example, is it known or conjectured that for a fixed coefficient ap>0 (for a small prime p), say a5=4, the distribution of curves decreases with the rank. In the case a5=4, rank 2 curves are almost inexistent compared to rank 0 and 1 curves. @BrandonCarter

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be a non-CM elliptic curve. By the [Sato–Tate conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sato%E2%80%93Tate_conjecture), which has been proven for elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$,  for any two real numbers $\alpha, \beta$ with $0\le \alpha<\beta\le\pi$, we have
$$\lim _{N\to\infty}\frac{\#\{p\le N:2\alpha\sqrt p \le a_p\le 2\beta\sqrt p\}}{\#\{p\le N\}}=\frac2\pi\int^\beta_\alpha\sin^2\theta \ d\theta.$$

In particular, the $a_p$'s are distributed according to a measure that does not depend on the rank.

A refinement of the conjecture (and still a conjecture), due to Lang and Trotter, predicts that, for a given non-zero integer $a$, we have
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\#\{p\le N : a_p = a\}}{\#\{p\le N\}} = c(E, a)\frac{\sqrt X}{\log X},$$
where $c(E, a)$ is an explicit constant. Again, there is no dependence on the rank.

These conjectures cover the case that $E$ is fixed, and we vary $p$. Your question is slightly different, in that you fix a prime $p$ and vary over all elliptic curves, but I think the answer should be the same: the specific value of $a_p$ should not affect the rank.

As for your observation: rank $2$ elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$ are just much rarer than rank $0$ and $1$ ones in general. In fact, it is conjectured that $100\%$ of elliptic curves have rank $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to relate what you say to my question so let me reformulate my observation which is that when the rank gets bigger, it seems like the values taken by $a_p$ tend to be negative for small prime index (gets more evenly distributed amongst rank 0,1,2 for larger primes from what I've seen). For example, there are almost no curves or rank 2 up to conductor 100 000 with $a_5=4$ but much more with rank 1 and much more with rank 0. thanks for your time !

Comment: If I've understood correctly, your observation is something like: among the elliptic curves $E$ with $a_5 = 4$ and conductor less than $N$, the proportion with rank 0 or 1 is much higher than the proportion of those with rank $2$. My point is that, among all elliptic curves $E$ with conductor less than $N$, it's also true that he proportion with rank 0 or 1 is much higher than the proportion of those with rank $2$. So it's not clear that having $a_5 = 4$ makes any difference. Have I misunderstood what you're observing?

Comment: It seems like, amongst all elliptic curves of conductor $\le N$, $\mathrm{Prob}(E\text{ has rank 2} \mid a_5 = 4)= \mathrm{Prob}(E \text{ has rank 2})$. It's just that both probabilities are small. As $N$ goes to infinity, conjecturally, the second probability goes to $0$.

Comment: yes indeed it will go to zero but my point is that when I take a random sample of the same size (say about 50k of each up to conductor 100.000) for curves of rank 0, 1 and 2, we observe that among the elliptic curves E with $a_5=4$ and conductor less than 100k, the proportion with rank 0 or 1 is much higher than the proportion of those with rank 2. This is the situation that interests me.

Comment: I feel like we're misunderstanding each other - was my summary of what you're observing correct? If I've understood, your observation is that rank 2 curves with $a_5 = 4$ are rare amongst elliptic curves of conductor up to 100,000. But, in order for this to be significant, you need to share that the rank 2 curves are *rarer* amongst those curves with $a_5 = 4$ than they are amongst all curves. By analogy, you could observe that amongst all the Tuesdays this year, the number of days where it snowed was very low. That doesn't mean there's any correlation between it snowing and it being Tuesday.